# Smoke/Carbon Monoxide Alarm Connection Issue Upon Replacement

Tags: electrical, wiring

A Kidde combination Smoke detector/Carbon Monoxide Alarm (hardwired, with battery backup) just recently expired here, and I ordered a new one (similar model I thought, didn't see exact one) to replace it with. When it arrived, to my surprise, I noticed that the a/c/ connecter receptacle in the new one was slightly different (recessed) than in the expired one (which was on the outside, more external), so that I couldn't just snap it in easily. The old harness with which alarm connects to a/c power had a slightly different connecting system.

Do I need to replace the harness? I hesitate to do so, as it is more complicated and dangerous electrically. Could I not just remove the small plastic gripping pieces on the sides of the old connecter, then it would seemingly slide in, but just lack the gripping parts. But I think they are essentially extraneous anyway, as the alarm is held in place when mounted by other means.

I called the company for assistance, but had trouble reaching someone.

Would appreciate help here if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The mounting plate for the sensor has to be installed to the cable if it's not a same for same swap, you cannot do any other way, once the mounting plate is secured to the ceiling the sensor will just click into place.  I could not give an answer to your actual question because you did not give the model numbers of both devices for an defined answer.

Comment: Please post images and model numbers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the wire harness must be replaced when changing to a model with different connection.

Whether or not to DIY is your decision.  There are other folks who can help.